# Installing Xubuntu recommended apps

Tags: software-recommendation, xubuntu, default-programs

I recently installed Xubuntu over my Ubuntu 11.10 installation (I sometimes can't stand Unity) without installing the recommended applications. How can I now install them?

Answer (score 3):

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop` should pick up the missing packages.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install Xubuntu? Did you do: sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop ? If so , you have installed the recommended apps.

Look at: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/xfce
and: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/purexfce

Also interesting is: http://wiki.xfce.org/de/recommendedapps

Comment: I ran: sudo  apt-get install xubuntu --no-install-recommends (or somesuch), I didn't install the recommended apps.

Answer (score -1):

Install [Ubuntu Desktop](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ubuntu-desktop), then choose one of the *many* shells Ubuntu provides, such as [Xfce4-panel](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xfce4-panel). It's just an app. You don't have to replace the operating system in order to switch to another text editor, file browser, web browser or panel. You just install and run it.